# how to get string between two strings

Tags: linux, bash, awk, grep

so for example, I have a string like this:

```
f=awerawet1351&q=aet12462awera&l=3ewar462&h=awiejt361
```

and I wanna grab the substring between "q=" and "&", which is "aet12462awera" or "q=aet12462awera" is also fine. 
I tried to use`awk -F'&'` , but the thing is, the position for "q="string is not fixed. Sometimes, I will have

```
f= .... & l=.... &q=....& h=....
```

so I can't use `awk -F'&' '{print $2}'` to get the result.

Is there anyway for me to use unix command to get it?
Thanks!

Comment: `grep -oP '(?<=(?|&)q=)[^&]*' <<< "?$querystring"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
STRING='f=awerawet1351&q=aet12462awera&l=3ewar462&h=awiejt361'
echo $STRING | awk -F"q=" '{print $2}' | cut -f1 -d"&"
```

Comment: Yes! It did the trick! Though I am still wondering that if this the most efficient way?

Answer (score 0):

```bash
string='f=awerawet1351&q=aet12462awera&l=3ewar462&h=awiejt361'
IFS='&'
for field in $string; do
    if [ "${field%=*}" = "q" ]; then
        echo ${field#*=}
    fi
done
```

Look at [parameter expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) and [IFS](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-IFS).